# Hosting ASP.NET Application in Amazon Server

Tags: asp.net, security, amazon-web-services

We have developed ASP.NET Application using SQL Server Database & hosted in our Company Intranet Server. The Application using Forms Authentication which checks user in the Active Directory. We have not concentrated much on Security checks due to its in Intranet.  Now our question is what are the possible security risk we need to concentrate on our Application If we host in Amazon Server. Also Can we get separate Account like VPN to access our Application in the Amazon Server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to concentrate on security as the AWS are for internet. Check if you can encrypt the data. Also, it differs from organization perspective. Check with your IT department first.